# Contador django python

Tags: python, mysql, django

tengo un pequeño problema:
Tengo un contador que indica la cantidad de Notas que tiene un cliente. Cada vez agrego una nota nueva a la base de datos (mysql) empieza en 0. Logre hacer que empiece en 1, pero al sumar otra nota la mismo cliente, se vuelve a repetir el 1, pero al cargar el tercero aparece un 2 y desde esa carga empieza a contar bien digamos.

Este es mi código:

```
notas = Notas.objects.filter(cliente=cliente)
contador = notas.count()

if  contador == 0:
    contador = 1
elif contador != 0:
    contador + 1
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este codigo no demuestra tu problema.. necesitamos un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

tiene que mirar los **tipos de operadores Python**

Link : https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/python-operators/

uno de los Operadores son de asignación

****=, :=, +=, -=, *=, etc.****

la operacion le suma, pero no es asignado a la variable

Operacion 1

```
 contador = contador + 1
```

Operacion 2

```
contador += 1
```